# Excel AutoRepublish error/Auto close windows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

One of my coworkers has 9 Excel workbooks that query a production server, organize the data and output .mht's as 'Dashboards' for production workers.

Some of them query every 3 minutes, some of them only every hour.

We see 2 general errors.

This one

[image]

and this one

[image]

which actually comes after an "Invalid Web Query" error with only an "OK" button.

This is not really an issue at this point as it rarely happens and only when the file it is reading is locked.

The first error only happens on a save when the target file is locked.  I have put `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before every save Macro in each book but it has not gotten rid of the top error.

I have tried to put an intermediate file into the mess and had no improvement.

Today, I tried [this in AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/149593-popupclear-close-popup-windows-and-message-boxes/) and it can kill the second error but fails with every (I'm pretty sure) combination of 'keys' as the author puts it.

It works if I have it look for Excel in general but that kills my sheet as well.

I can and do click the "Do not show..." every time but when we push updates to this computer and restart it, these errors come back and it can take days for all of the conflicts to show themselves.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Why don't you just check if the target file is locked and then abort the save if it is? Then you won't get the error in the first place ;)

Comment: So you're talkin VBA in the Sheet before save?

Comment: Exactly, you got it ;) I assume you are using VBA for all this dashboard stuff ...

Comment: Yea, I think I can use this `If GetAttr("c:\test.xls") And vbReadOnly Then` and loop it with the `wait to publish` sub in the sheet.  Always right in front of my face...  VB is not my strong suit.

Comment: Good luck. And don't forget to answer your own question. I don't know VBA at all - but as an ex Java/C++/C/Fortran/Basic programmer I know how to think about problems and I like lateral thinking ;)

Comment: Chip Pearson's [Wait for File Close](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/WaitForFileClose.htm) page might be helpful.

Comment: For sure, I'm hoping the smaller code works.  If it works I'll have to expand the `If` statement for all the .mht's published by each sheet.  There are 25 total for 9 workbooks, between 2 and 5 per book.  The 'flow' chart for this looks like a drunken spider's web.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution in testing - surrounding the ActiveWorkbook.Save with the below If statement and using another sub to pause.

```
Sub PUBLISH()
'Call TIME
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If GetAttr("Z:\CHGME\_Production Scheduling\ADMIN\7 Day WIP.mht") And vbReadOnly Then
    Application.Run "Sheet1.WAITtoPUBLISH"
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If
End Sub

`Private Sub WAITtoPUBLISH()    
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "PUBLISH"
End Sub
```

It has been holding for 2 days now.  I can still break it with the right timing so the "Wait to Close" option may be the long-term solution.